# react-konva warning 'Konva' is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, konvajs, react-konva

I'm trying to learn how to use the canvas in react via a package called react-konva.  npm installation was simple enough, and I added some demo code that works...

```
// in MainComponent.js
import {Stage, Layer, Rect} from 'react-konva';

// in render()
<Stage width={700} height={70}>
  <Layer  fill={'red'}>
    <Rect ... and so on
```

My code mentions `Konva` in the context of getting a color...

```
Konva.Util.getRandomColor()
```

but my browser warns appropriately: "**warning 'Konva' is not defined**".  I tried this...

```
import {Konva, Stage, ... } from 'react-konva';
```

but that makes things worse, generating **undefined** errors wherever I try to use `Konva.`.  I tried adding a reference directly to konva...

```
// in index.js
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/konvajs/konva/1.3.0/konva.js"></script>
```

but then I get this error:

> Konva instance is already exist in current eviroment. Please use only
>   one instance.

(grammar error and misspellings in the original error message)

Would appreciate a pointer, or any thoughts about what might be causing this.

Comment: did you also do `npm install konva` ?

Comment: Nope.  And that fixes it.  Thanks so much!  I misread the one liner npm install instruction on the github page.  Feel free to add an answer that I can mark correct

Comment: I've added my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment in your question. You have forgotten to do `npm install konva`.

Answer (score 2):

**Try to use** `const Konva= window.Konva`

this will allow you use vanilla KonvaJS properties.